# Xamarin form: Tabbed Page Tabs not rendered properly on android

Tags: android, xamarin, tabbar, tabbedpage

I have problem rendering the tabs in tabbedPage.

I have two tabs:

Tab 2:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="Provider.Pages.SignInOut.ProjectFix.TestPage2"             
         Title="Accounted">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout><Label Text="asdf454545"></Label></StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Tab 1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Provider.Pages.SignInOut.ProjectFix.TestPage"
             Title="Unaccounted">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="asdf"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The tabbedPage which hosted those tabs is:

```
 public class TestTabbedPage : TabbedPage 
{
    public TestTabbedPage()
    {
        Children.Add(new TestPage());
        Children.Add(new TestPage2());
    }
}
```

The problem i have here is it does show two tabs but the last tabs don't have the name included and the text was not on the screen

[image]

If I duplicate the page with Tab 1 instead of Tab 2, everything works fine.

What am i doing wrong with the tabs why does tab 2 not showing properly on the screen.

This actually giving me headache because I have actual project which have two tabs but when rendered the tabs was gone. In the same project, I have the other pages which have tabs but they all showing fine.

Comment: Make sure `TestPage2` is calling `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor

Comment: did you modify Tabbar.xaml from android project?

Comment: I realized is because i have subclass the TabbarRenderer which not render anything on android so the tabs not showing. I have removed and is fine